# Full website version didn't load in Firefox

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have responsible mobile version where are button "go to desktop version":

```
<div class="desktop_version">
  <a href="#" onclick="submitinfo();"><em class="fa fa-desktop"></em> Desktop version</a>
</div>
```

after submit i need send value to mobile.php (ajax) and set $_SESSION['mobile_style']. jQuery code:

```
function submitinfo() {
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/mobile.php", 
  data: {values:"mobile"}
  });
  window.location.href = "http://dekstopversionexample.lt";
}
```

and mobile.php:

```
session_start();
    $_SESSION['mobile_style'] = $_POST['values'];
```

it seems as if everything is fine, in responsinator.com with Chrome all good, but in Fiefox i got error POST http://myaddress.lt/mobile.php. With some mobile device same problem after click button. Nothing changes, i cant achieve desktop version and session is not saved.

thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change window.location in a success callback since it may happen before the asynchronous POST request is finished.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/mobile.php", 
  data: {values:"mobile"}
  success: function(){
    window.location = "http://dekstopversionexample.lt";
  }
});
```